# How do I set a time delay between 2 screenshot-desktop calls?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

**screenshot-desktop** is a promise based npm API which takes the desktop screenshot and stores it when called.

However, I need to call the function thrice and set a **delay of 5 secs** between each call.
Since this is a promise API, their execution takes place instantly. Can I create a delay between my calls?

```
const screenshot = require('screenshot-desktop');
screenshot({filename:'a.jpg'});
//need delay of 5 secs here
screenshot({filename:'b.jpg'});
//another delay of 5 secs needed here
screenshot({filename:'c.jpg'});
```

Obviously, setTimeout and setInterval functions do not work with these promise-based APIs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I advise you to use promises in the following way:

```
const screenshot = require('screenshot-desktop');
const delay = (ms = 100) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

async function init() {
    screenshot({filename:'a.jpg'});
    await delay(5000);
    screenshot({filename:'b.jpg'});
    await delay(5000);
    screenshot({filename:'c.jpg'});
}

init();
```

With asyncronous functions you can use `await` to stop processing until a given condition or event is met. In this case the "event" is a timer that takes 5000 milliseconds to finish.

If an asyncronous function throw an error, you can catch it by using the `catch` method or the second argument of the `then` method like so:

```
init().then(function(result) {
    console.log("The async function finished sucessfully and returned the following:");
    console.log(result);
}, function (err) {
    console.log("The async function failed with the following error:");
    console.log(err);
});
```